# Hide JSF 2 URL after the application name

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, friendly-url

I need to deploy my JSF2 application in Tomcat 7 with two simple urls, like this:

www.rdauctions.com
and 
www.rdauctions.com/backoffice

(The first is for the public application and the second for the admin app.)

I want nothing else to show in the URL. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this with a servlet filter and a JSF view handler, but the simplest solution is probably to just use [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/).

Comment: Thanks, Arjan. Can you please elaborate? I'm currently using myfaces-2.1.4.

Comment: You'd best start here: http://ocpsoft.com/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.2/en-US/html/ read the introduction, play a bit with the examples. If you still don't understand it, you can ask a more specific question here or at the dedicated OCP forums. Good luck!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see the link now. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Great. So easy. Thanks again, Arjan.